# Confused about writing out electron configurations

Tags: atoms, electrons, electronic-configuration

I watched the Crash Course chemistry video about the electron. In the video Hank showed an example configuration of iron as $\mathrm{(1s)^2 (2s)^2 (2p)^6 (3s)^2 (3p)^6 (4s)^2 (3d)^6}$ and explained that due to energy constraints, electrons go to the s orbital of the 4th shell before going into the d orbital of the 3rd shell and so they are written in this order.

I looked up [iron in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron) and there the configuration is given as $\mathrm{[Ar](3d)^6 (4s)^2}$. I understand how it's shortened with argon, but why in Wikipedia is the d orbital of the 3rd shell written before the s orbital of the 4th shell?

Which one is preferred?

Answer (score 2):

> For a given configuration, the order of writing the orbitals is not
>   completely fixed since only the orbital occupancies have physical
>   significance. For example, the electron configuration of the titanium
>   ground state can be written as either $\mathrm{[Ar] \, 4s^2 3d^2}$ or $\mathrm{[Ar] \, 3d^2 4s^2}$.
>   The first notation follows the order based on the [Madelung rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aufbau_principle#Madelung_energy_ordering_rule) for
>   the configurations of neutral atoms; $\mathrm{4s}$ is filled before $\mathrm{3d}$ in the
>   sequence $\ce{Ar, K, Ca, Sc, Ti}$. The second notation groups all orbitals
>   with the same value of $n$ together, corresponding to the
>   "spectroscopic" order of orbital energies that is the reverse of the
>   order in which electrons are removed from a given atom to form
>   positive ions; $\mathrm{3d}$ is filled before $\mathrm{4s}$ in the sequence $\ce{Ti^4+, Ti^3+, Ti^2+, Ti+, Ti}$.

Source: [Wikipedia article on electron configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_configuration).